# Can I use a combo box to change the table a form saves data to in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access

I have created an MS Access form to insert data to tables. I want to store data to **separate** tables.

How can I use a *combo box* in the form to **select the target table** in each entry.

Comment: I don't know Access but I hope this 'concept' may help. The idea is the text of the combo box matches the name of the database. When the 'save' button is clicked, you need to pass the value of the combo box as a variable and insert that variable into your SQL script.

Comment: That's the problem. I want to know that SQL script. I have no Idea.

Comment: Are the fields identical in all the tables? If so, it makes me wonder why have separate tables for all the records. If the fields are not identical, that makes it incredibly difficult to use the same form for different tables. Can you give us some idea of how the tables and form are set up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are identical.
As an example, I enter details of people using a **form**(name, age, sex).
Then I want to generate two tables automatically according to **sex**(male and female).
One table for males and other table for females.